# Custom authentication token for custom Users in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework, django-authentication

I am very new to Django Framework, I am trying to use Custom user model and Custom authentication  for my project.

please find below code for Create Custom Model and Custom authentication.

**Custom User Model**

```
   class User(AbstractUser):
    userID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    Employee = models.ForeignKey(EMP, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

**User Serializer**

```
class ValidateUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('Employee', 'first_name', 'last_name',
                  'email', 'username', 'password')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        User = get_user_model()
        Employee = validated_data.pop('Employee')
        first_name = validated_data.pop('first_name')
        last_name = validated_data.pop('last_name')
        email = validated_data.pop('email')
        username = validated_data.pop('username')
        password = validated_data.pop('password')

  
        return User.objects.create(Employee =Employee ,
                                   first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name,  email=email, username=username, password=None, **validated_data)
```

**Views.py**

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def users(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        users = Users.objects.all()
        print(users.query)
        data = UserTempSerializer(users, many=True).data
        return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        users_data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        user_serilizer = ValidateUserSerializer(data=users_data)
        if user_serilizer.is_valid():
            user_serilizer.save()
            return JsonResponse(user_serilizer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        print(user_serilizer.errors)
        return JsonResponse(user_serilizer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

***Custom authentication Code Here***:

```
class CustomAuthToken(ObtainAuthToken):

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data,
                                           context={'request': request})
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data['user']
        token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        return Response({
            'token': token.key,
            'user_id': user.pk,
            'first_name': user.first_name,
            'email': user.email
        })
```

I am not able to create the users and not able to authincate users.
I am getting below error try to authenticate the user:

```
Bad Request: /api/auth/
[06/Jul/2021 10:59:38] "POST /api/auth/ HTTP/1.1" 400 68
```

Could you please anybody help, Do I made wrong or flow are wrong.

Thanks in advance !!!!

Comment: Do you have any traceback or if you can show what the cause of the 400 is?

Comment: @bdbd, Not Sure about why I am getting this issue, I am trying to call from Angualr or PostMan Client, I am getting this isssue